# Getting the total size of all log files

Tags: scripting

Using du -h: how to sum up the file size of
file1,
file 2,
file 3...located in various directories.

I believe it can be done via script, but I have no idea how to perform arithmetic out of different outputs in the terminal.

Comment: I would like to know the total size of different files from different directories. I tried du -h file 1 file 2 file 3, and du -h file 1 + file 2...Are you suggesting I should read the manual for du?

Comment: Yep. Im suggesting. If I execute `du -ach ./.cache/pip/selfcheck.json Downloads/PDFMaker1.0.1.tar` I get a total in the last line. (36K total)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-c` / `--total` option to get the total size.

To get the last line containing the "total" value:

```
du -hc /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/filex | tail -n1
```

Or the last line without the "total" string:

```
du -hc /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/filex | tail -n1 | cut -f1
```

Comment: They have a point: I should have read the manual for du.