# How to list all files and get the total size of all files in an sftp server?

Tags: ssh, ls, sftp, size

I am connected to an sftp server using

```
sftp -i key.pem user@server
```

The server contains logs and I can list logs up to 4 days old using `ls`. The problem is that ls does not seem to be able to fetch than 4 day old logs. I am wondering how can I list all the logs in the directory and get their total size?

A similar question about the size has been asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596612/getting-the-total-size-of-all-log-files) and provides a solution using `du -hc`. But this command does not exist on my sftp server neither I have ssh access. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`lftp` has a `du` command and does support the `sftp` protocol:

```
lftp sftp://user@host
```

Or to specify the ssh key to use and skip the password prompt:

```
lftp -e 'set sftp:connect-program ssh -axi key.pem' sftp://user:@host
```

And run `du` (or `du -ba` to list each file along with their size in bytes, or `du -ha` to use suffixes) at the `sftp` prompt. Note that it's different from the Unix `du` command in that it gives the apparent size as opposed to disk usage and doesn't include the size of directory files.

If `ls` doesn't list files older than 4 days, the most likely explanation is that they're not or no longer there. The `ls` command of the `sftp` or `lftp` client will just perform a ["read directory" query or series of queries in the SFTP protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13#section-8.2.2) to retrieve the directory contents. If the server doesn't send what's there and you don't have any way to access the data other than over SFTP, there's little else you can do.